# viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false) select, but doesn't scroll to highlighted Tab

Tags: android, scroll, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have `ViewPager` with connected `TabLayout`. If I use `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true)` the correct tab on the tab layout is shown (`TabLayout` automatically scrolls to the selected tab). But I want to use `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false)`.In this case correct tab is selected (highlighted) but the problem is that `TabLayout` doesn't scroll to this selected tab. It is hidden and I have to manual slide `TabLayout` to see what tab is selected. Is it a bug? Can I manually force `TabLayout` to scroll to the selected tab?

*Update:*

To be clear. My tab is properly selected and correct View is shown in `ViewPager` when performing `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true)` or `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, false)`. But with the second one, `TabLayout` doesn't scroll so my selected (highlighted) `Tab` is hidden.

*Update 2:*

I have opened the issue with a sample app: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72390853

Comment: This Question is not clear. The "... correct tab is selected but the problem is that tab layout doesn't scroll to this selected tab"? Do you mean the `Tab` does not move or the `ViewPager` is not showing the correct `View`?

Comment: @Barns Tab is not moved (selected tab is hidden), ViewPager shows correct View.

Comment: Sorry my solution didn't work. I thought adding the `TabLayout.Tab tab = mMainTabLayout.getTabAt(position);
            tab.select();` is what might be missing. Perhaps you could add all relevant code to your Post. Then we can step through your code to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: are you changing tab programmatically for a particular condition ?

Comment: Before calling `setCurrentItem` I'm changing tabs in my `PagerAdapter` and call  `notifyDataSetChanged()`. I have opened the issue with a sample app: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72390853

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, I use this workaround waiting a fix :

After I setup the viewPager2 and the tabLayout, I use a delay before setting the current item.
I play with the invisibility of tabLayout to have a smoother display.

```
binding.tabLayout.isInvisible = true
binding.viewPager.apply {
    adapter = FragmentStateAdapter(this)
    TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, this) { tab, position ->
        tab.text = "text"
    }.attach()

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        delay(100)
        setCurrentItem(X, false)
        binding.tabLayout.isInvisible = false
    }
}
```